# Nodemon -w keeps starting, without running the server

Tags: javascript, typescript, nodemon

When I run `nodemon dist/index.js` nodemon runs the server, but if I use `nodemon -w dist/index.js`, it just keeps starting, without actually running my server.

I transpiled my index.js file from Typescript and it looks like this:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const App_1 = require("./App");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
App_1.default.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    return console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

As far as I can tell the .js file doesn't change anymore after I transpiled it from typescript using the `tsc -b` command.

What could cause nodemon to keep starting? And how do I fix it?

Comment: why are you using -w?

Comment: I want to build a dev script using nodemon and tsc, where when I change my typescript while running my server, it automatically transpiles into node.js and nodemon then picks up the changes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With nodemon is better use ts-node. This library is good for development because with ts-lint you can run TypeScript file.

nodemon.json
```

```
{
    "watch": ["server/**/*.ts"],
    "execMap": {
        "ts": "ts-node"
    }
}
```

```

package.json

`"dev": "nodemon server/index.ts"`